# Cannot call tasks gives module not found celery error

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have the following implementation for celery and this is not a Django project

Project structure

```
proj
   |
    proj
    ├── celery.py
    ├── conf.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── run.py
    └── tasks.py
```

`conf.py`

```
broker_url = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
result_backend = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
task_serializer = "json"
timezone = "Europe/London"
enable_utc = True
include = ['proj.tasks']
beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-2-seconds': {
        'task': 'proj.tasks.test',
        'schedule': 2.0,
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```

`run.py`

```
from proj.tasks import add

res = add.delay(2, 2)

print(res.get())
```

`tasks.py`

```
from proj.celery import app


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(2.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')

    # Calls test('world') every 30 seconds
    sender.add_periodic_task(3.0, test.s('world'), expires=10)


@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@app.task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

When following the tutorial `celery.py`

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

from proj import conf

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object(conf)

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

`proj celery -A proj worker -l info` works though

When running run.py getting the error

```
from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'
```

renaming celery.py to another name will cause

```
proj celery -A proj worker -l info
Error: 
Unable to load celery application.
Module 'proj' has no attribute 'celery'
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Rename `celery.py` to something other than "celery". `celery_app.py` maybe

Comment: Tried that approach then command
proj celery -A proj worker -l info
Error: 
Unable to load celery application.
Module 'proj' has no attribute 'celery' fail

Comment: Try `celery -A celery_app worker`

Comment: celery_app is not a module celery -A needs a module